# KDB: How to parse a json file?

Tags: json, parsing, dictionary, kdb

I created a config file in JSON format, and I want to use KDB to read it in as a dictionary.

In Python, it's so easy:

```
with open('data.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

Is there a similar function in KDB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To read your JSON file into kdb+, you should use `read0`. This returns the lines of the file as a list of strings.

```
q)read0`:sample.json
,"{"
"\"name\":\"John\","
"\"age\":30,"
"\"cars\":[ \"Ford\", \"BMW\", \"Fiat\" ]"
,"}"
```

kdb+ allows for the de-serialisation (and serialisation) of JSON objects to dictionaries using the `.j` namespace. The inbuilt `.j.k` expects a single string of characters containing json and converts this into a dictionary. A `raze` should be used to flatten our list of strings:

```
q)raze read0`:sample.json
"{\"name\":\"John\",\"age\":30,\"cars\":[ \"Ford\", \"BMW\", \"Fiat\" ]}"
```

Finally, using `.j.k` on this string yields the dictionary

```
q).j.k raze read0`:sample.json
name| "John"
age | 30f
cars| ("Ford";"BMW";"Fiat")
```

For a particularly large JSON file, it may be more efficient to use `read1` rather than `raze read0` on your file, e.g.

```
q).j.k read1`:sample.json
name| "John"
age | 30f
cars| ("Ford";"BMW";"Fiat")
```

If you're interested in the reverse operation, you can use `.j.j` to convert a dictionary into a list of strings and use `0:` to save.

Further information on the `.j` namespace can be found [here](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotj/).
You can also see more examples on the Kx wiki of [read0](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filewords/#read0), [read1](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filewords/#read1) and [0:](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#save-text).

Answer (score 4):

Working with JSON is handled by the `.j` namespace where `.j.j` serialises and `.j.k` deserialises the messages. Note the you will need to use `raze` to convert the JSON into a single string first.

There is more information available on the [Kx wiki](https://code.kx.com/q/ref/dotj/), where the following example is presented:

```
q).j.k "{\"a\":[0,1],\"b\":[\"hello\",\"world\"]}"
a| 0       1
b| "hello" "world"
```

Answer (score 2):

When using `.j.j` both symbols and strings in kdb will be encoded into a JSON string while kdb will decode JSON strings to kdb strings except keys where they will be symbols.

To encode a kdb table in JSON an array of objects with identical keys should be sent. kdb will also encode tables as arrays of objects in JSON.

```
q).j.k "[{\"a\":1,\"b\":2},{\"a\":3,\"b\":4}]"
a b
---
1 2
3 4
```

When encoding q will use the value of `\P` to choose the precision, which is by default 7 which could lead to unwanted rounding.

This can be changed with 0 meaning maximum precision although the final digits are unreliable as shown below. See here for more info https://code.kx.com/q/ref/cmdline/#-p-display-precision.

```
q).j.j 1.000001 1.0000001f
"[1.000001,1]"

q)\P 0
q).j.j 1.000001 1.0000001f
"[1.0000009999999999,1.0000001000000001]"
```